# cakephp 3 rest errors return as html CrudJsonApi

Tags: json, rest, api, cakephp-3.0

I'm adding a REST API onto an existing cakephp codebase.

It is working as I expect.  I hit /api/v1/contacts/12312 and get json data back for contact 12312. If put an id of a contact that doesn't exist then I get the html 404 page error rather than json.

This happens internally on the contacts->get($id) line.

In the api app controller I have

```
 public function initialize()
    {

        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Crud.Crud', [
            'actions' => [
                'Crud.Index',
                'Crud.View',
                'Crud.Add',
                'Crud.Edit',
                'Crud.Delete'
            ],
            'listeners' => [
                'CrudJsonApi.JsonApi',
                'CrudJsonApi.Pagination', // Pagination != ApiPagination
                'Crud.ApiQueryLog',


            ],
            'Error' => [
                'errorLevel' => E_ALL,
                'exceptionRenderer' => 'CrudJsonApi\Error\JsonApiExceptionRenderer',
                'skipLog' => [],
                'log' => true,
                'trace' => true,
        ],
        ]);



        $this->Crud->config(['listeners.jsonApi.exceptionRenderer' => 'CrudJsonApi\Error\JsonApiExceptionRenderer']);

        $this->setJsonResponse();
    }



public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
    $this->response->type('application/json');
    $this->set('_serialize', true);
}
```

I thought using the JsonApiExceptionRenderer 404 errors would be handled with json output.

Also the Pagination works but the Pagination data isnt returned with the response...

```
{
  "viewVar": "crmContacts",
  "crmContacts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "lastname": "testname1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "lastname": "smith"
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you wrap the command with try/catch?

Comment: You should use "find" instead of "get" if you don't want to handle an exception when the record doesn't exist

Comment: I am not familiar with the Crud JSON API plugin (please always mention the software that you are using!), but according to the docs, you're not configuring things correctly, the `JsonApiExceptionRenderer` is ment to be set in the application configuration, not the `Crud` component configuration. **https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud-json-api/blob/0.4.0/docs/preface/setup.rst#exception-handler**

Comment: I have solved this now. It shouldn't of had the beforerender code. Thanks